# shifting the rows of data

Tags: awk, sed

In the text file I've to move the rows matching the country name with the information.

Sample text is:

> **U.S.A**
>
> Washington    English     9,372,610 sq km
>
> **France**
>
> Paris     French      547,030 sq km

Desired o/p:

> U.S.A Washington  English     9,372,610 sq km
>
> France    Paris       French      547,030 sq km

**Is there any way I can do this using sed or by using awk**?

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 'N;s/\n/ /' file
U.S.A Washington English 9,372,610 sq km
France Paris French 547,030 sq km
```

Append the next line to pattern space using `N` which is separated by a `\n` followed by a simple substitution to replace the `\n` with space.

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%2?FS:RS)}1' file
U.S.A Washington English 9,372,610 sq km
France Paris French 547,030 sq km
```

Set the Output Record Separator to space for every line except second line where you set it to newline using Record Separator.

Using `paste`:

```
$ paste -d " " - - < file
U.S.A Washington English 9,372,610 sq km
France Paris French 547,030 sq km
```

`-d " "` sets the delimiter to space. `- -` allows us to buffer two lines from the file and print it together separated by the delimiter.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Added an explanation. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ha, now I got it - the input is not two times stdin, but paste reads alternating from it's two inputs, which are the same, so reading one line for left consumes the line, so when then reading right, the next line is read. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are cleanly interleaved as pairs, you could separate both kinds of lines in two files, and then paste them together left and right:

```
$ <countries.txt grep ' sq km$' > countries-loc.txt
$ <countries.txt grep -v -e ' sq km$' -e '^$' > countries-state.txt 
$ paste -d ' ' countries-state.txt countries-loc.txt
    U.S.A           Washington English 9,372,610 sq km
    France          Paris French 547,030 sq km
```

Cleaning up multiple spaces, and spaces on start of line:

```
$ paste -d ' ' countries-state.txt countries-loc.txt | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^ //'
U.S.A Washington English 9,372,610 sq km
France Paris French 547,030 sq km
```